# R studio time column is between

Tags: r

I have a table called "test". In that table I have a column "Time".
The Time column is (as an example): 13:03:36 or 15:40:39
I want another column to be: 13 - 14 or 15 - 16.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

test["Category"] <- if_else(test$Time < "15:00:00", "13-14", "15-16")
```

This is the simplest solution for the provided example. If you need more categories, you would need a more scalable code:

```
test$Category <- sapply(test$Time, function(x) paste0(sub(":\\d\\d:\\d\\d", "", x), "-", as.numeric(sub(":\\d\\d:\\d\\d", "", x))+1))
```